# Failed Reopen audit — Why is this unclear?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Failed a Reopen audit on: [Return a list from class (Entity Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55232030/return-a-list-from-class-entity-framework)

Comments indicated the question wasn't originally posted in English, but clearly it was edited, and it seems fairly clear (OP wants to "display the column NAME", showed code etc) and free of "serious problems", so why is this a failed audit to nominate this for reopening?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The question doesn't state what their error is, doesn't say what they want their code to do, have a very incomplete snippet, and their code is broken in a very straightforward way that would be explained by them just putting the error text into a search engine.  That the question is in English doesn't mean it's suddenly a good question.  Why do you think that's a good question?  You say that the OP wants to display the column "name".  How do they want to display the name, what problems are they having displaying the name?  "Display the column name" isn't a clear question.

Comment: I never said it was a "good" question, but it seems closing because "unclear what you're asking" doesn't seem to be appropriate, at least in the context of the confusing comments (which were removed) and the audit.

Comment: So what's the problem they're having?  How do they want to display their column?  What UI framework are they using, how do they want to show the data, etc.?  Why can't they display their column?  What is the code needed to reproduce the problem they're having?  Just because the question is no longer in another language doesn't mean it's a clear question.

Comment: As I said, I am aware that the question is not ideal; I was mainly focused on the confusing nature of the audit question. Which appears now to have been resolved, so no further discussion is really necessary.

Comment: [You're not the first one to fail an audit on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55232030/timeline). Apparently it's confused a lot of people.

Comment: On one hand I guess it's a reasonable test whether someone's paying attention to the actual question, but having those comments there was confusing since it made it seem that the reason the question was closed was no longer valid. But if it still deserves to be closed in spite of that, I guess it shouldn't be nominated for reopening.

Comment: Same as others the reopen queue require you to be qualified enough to cast your vote. "Skip" should be a default option. Only if you know what question is asking about, only if you are able to distinguish "leave closed" or "reopen" (possibly after YOUR edit, not someone else), only then you can skip "Skip". You failed not because audit was bad, but because question was bad and it  *"seems fairly clear"* to you and you wanted to screw other people close-votes by re-opening poor question.

Answer (score 5):

As you noticed, the post was first created in spanish, and later translated in english.

It possibly entered the audits list at that point, and stayed there afterwards. Seeing that the actual post was already closed could have hinted you that this was an audit.

At that point, casting a reopen vote **from outside of the review task** if you feel it deserves it and skipping or giving the right answer for the audit is a way to go.

---

That being said, I am not an expert in that framework, but it does look like someone is having mismatched types problems, which is in my experience quickly closed. These questions have duplicates so even if it looks clear, depending on the age of the framework it's possibly answered already.

Comment: Exactly — given that it was in English and the comments indicated it used to not be in English, it looked like it should not be closed anymore. And I did cast a reopen vote, but I was told I was wrong because it is an audit.

And if it's a duplicate, then it should be closed as a duplicate, not closed as "unclear what you're asking". Either way, it shouldn't be used for auditing. I'm not an expert in the framework either, but I don't think you necessarily need to be in order to do reviews.

Comment: oh, sorry I was unclear @shim, I meant casting a reopen vote **from outside of the queue**. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh, yea that makes sense. Although I think nominating reopening is a privilege I may not have earned yet? Either I'm not particularly concerned about this question getting reopened, more that it's being used for auditing when it's not really a good example (anymore?).

Comment: Oh possibly, I'm not sure about that :)

Comment: Oh looks like someone reopened it already

Comment: @shim Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) on reopen/close-priveleges (3000 rep is needed for the so-called 'Moderation Privilege')

Comment: Thanks, I think I already have the privilege, just the question was already reopened by the time I looked at it.